# inserting different columns in single csv in different tables of mysql at same time

Tags: mysql, csv, import-csv

> i have single CSV file which contains 11 columns some them belongs to different MySQL tables , how can i insert or load this CSV data in single operation or query

1. it is possible to load data by reading CSV file but when all the columns belong to same table
2. what to do when each or some columns belongs to different tables

Comment: Use `LOAD DATA` and then move the data to another column from within MySQL.  Not clear why you would want to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we have client they used to store data in excel sheet since we are automating the process we are using mysql db we want to load their existing data in database

Comment: Refer to my first comment.

Comment: yes thanks will try